# how to display images of one project in another project in MVC 5 path stored in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two MVC 5 projects in one solution. Projects are
1. Admin
2. UserWebsite.

I have saved many images in Admin project and path in database. Now i wish to display this images
in "UserWebsite" project pages using path. When I get file path and give to image source in page,  then only coming string in image src, but no image.

What is the proper way to display images of Admin project in UserWebsite. should i add path in app setting(web.config) in UserWebsite. Please i need complete explanation with code. I am on local host.

Comment: Are you saving the relative or absolute file path? can you provide screenshots?

Comment: Show us what you tried. A small bit of code of what you are doing helps.

Comment: Thank you,  Sir. Problem has been solved. I just added Admin project local Host path in app setting and done. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

You could make a blob storage and save a key to your blob in your Database and download the pictures with a controller or save the images in the www3root files of your Client. I would prefer the first one because this gives you the ability to easily delete old images and they are saved anonymous.